# How do I draw this tree pattern in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, binary-tree

Given a height  1<=h<=15, how do I go about drawing this tree? I'll need to be able to traverse it later to solve some questions.

For h = 1, just the root labeled 1.

For h = 2,

```
 3
1 2
```

For h = 3,

```
    7
  3   6
 1 2 4 5
```

etc.

All that really strikes so far has been trying to find a relation from the top-down (for the left side tree, the left node will be (parent-1)/2 and the right child is parent-1 but this isn't a consistent pattern), but I can't seem to find anything . Since i need to be able to generate the tree, I'm not sure how to use a heap-structure either.  I'm not sure where to start on recursion either. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Depth-first search that labels nodes once it has visited all of their children

Comment: Are you sure that the number 1 is a leaf of the tree, at the bottom? It is usually placed at the root, the top of the tree. The formulas then become easier.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Yep, this is the thing.

Comment: For `h=4`, the right subtree is the left subtree with seven (the root of the left subtree) added to every element.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh these are some great ideas, thank you. I'm already working on them.

Comment: @RoryDaulton interesting perspective, will look into that idea as well.

Comment: @RoryDaulton the complement system doesn't work, because while 1 = 8-7 (for h=3), the left child would be 2 and the right child 3, so their complements would be 6 and 5 (which doesn't work out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tree could be drawn recursively, but here is non-recursive code.

```
def ruler(n):
    result = 1
    while not (n & 1):
        n >>= 1
        result += 1
    return result

def printtree(h):
    widthofnum = len(str(2**h - 1))
    for row in range(h, 0, -1):
        maxcol = 2**(h - row)
        width = 2**(row-1) * (widthofnum + 1) - 1
        valincr = 2**row - 2
        val = valincr + 1
        for col in range(1, maxcol + 1):
            print(str(val).center(width), end=' ')
            val += ruler(col) + valincr
        print()

printtree(3)
```

That prints

```
   7    
 3   6  
1 2 4 5
```

while `printtree(5)` gives

```
                       31                       
           15                      30           
     7           14          22          29     
  3     6     10    13    18    21    25    28  
1  2  4  5  8  9  11 12 16 17 19 20 23 24 26 27
```

The spacing may not be ideal for larger numbers, but it works. Note that each line ends in at least one space, for code simplicity. The print statement means this is Python 3.x code. This non-recursive code lets us print from top-to-bottom, left-to-right without any backtracking or storage of strings. However, that complicates the calculations involved.

One key to that code is the discrete [ruler function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RulerFunction.html), which can be defined as "the exponent of the largest power of 2 which divides 2n." It is more visually seen as the height of consecutive marks on an inch ruler. This determines the increases in values between numbers in a row. The rest of the code should be straightforward.

Comment: wow this is very helpful, thank you. As a further modification, I would like to build this as a tree so as to be able to traverse these nodes. ANy suggestions on that (or separate question)?

Comment: @tvishwa107: Yes, that should be a separate question, so go ahead and ask it separately. But make sure you clarify just what you mean by a "tree" since there are multiple ways to define one (a list, nested lists, instances of a class, etc.). Also state what data goes in each node of the tree, such as whether the numbers we used above are stored in the tree.